Shopify SEO- GSC Help
I am facing some issues about Shopify Product Links. First, i am throwing some example that might be help to understand the problem.
Case-1: https://mywebsite.com/products/someproduct
Case-2: https://mywebsite.com/collections/productcollection/products/someproduct
Case-3: https://mywebsite.com/collections/productcollection/products/someproduct?variants=234123
Case-4: https://mywebsite.com/products/someproduct?variants=234123
First of all in the above URLs in case-1 & case-2 both URL can be indexed? although they are same product.
Secondly, in case-1 & case-4 both url can be indexed? the product is and page is same. but the color change or quality change create the variants parameters. if it can indexed in Google then how?

Where are all the canonicals pointing for these pages that seem to have the same product but at different URLs? I would think a good way of organizing all of this would be to canonicalize the /products/someproduct page in all these cases because I assume the collections pages could go away at some point in the future while still offering the product.

Here is Google's documentation on canonicals. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Is it possible to index the main product and also the variant of the product at the same time? but the variant and real product page are the same and same content.

I would think of the pages are the same for the variant and parent product you will run into the issue of duplicate content. I assume they have different SKUs and if this is the case you could probably leverage schema to differentiate.
